# integrating $\int_{\gamma}e^zdz$ with $\gamma$ is the arc on the unit circle that unites one with i

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am stuck integrating $$\int_{\gamma}e^zdz$$
with $\gamma$ is the arc on the unit circle that unites one with i.

I tried this :

The integrand $\mathrm{e}^z$ is holomorphic for $\vert z \vert \le 1$, therefore the integral vanishes by the Cauchy integral theorem.

Now :
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
  \int_0^{2 \pi} \mathrm{e}^{\cos(\theta)} \cos(\theta + \sin(\theta)) \mathrm{d} \theta &=&
   \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} \theta} \left( \mathrm{e}^{\cos(\theta)} \sin(\sin(\theta))  \right) \mathrm{d} \theta = \left. \mathrm{e}^{\cos(\theta)} \sin(\sin(\theta)) \right|_0^{2\pi} = 0
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Indeed:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
  \mathrm{e}^{\cos(\theta)} \cos(\theta + \sin(\theta)) &=&  \mathrm{e}^{\cos(\theta)} \cos(\theta) \cos(\sin(\theta)) -  \mathrm{e}^{\cos(\theta)}  \sin(\theta) \sin(\sin(\theta) \\ 
   &=& \mathrm{e}^{\cos(\theta)} \cdot  \frac{\mathrm{d} \sin(\sin(\theta))}{\mathrm{d} \theta} + 
      \frac{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{e}^{\cos(\theta)}}{\mathrm{d} \theta} \cdot \sin(\sin(\theta)) \\
  &=& \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} \theta} \left( \mathrm{e}^{\cos(\theta)} \sin(\sin(\theta))  \right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Is that correct , please some help to solve this.

Comment: Please avoid using $$ in titles; it takes up an unnecessary amount of space on the front page. Also, your computation of the integral seems to be over the entire circle, not over the arc.

Comment: Also, there are two ways to connect $1$ and $i$ along the circle – clock- and counterclockwise.

Comment: then i will have two integrals one along the circle clock and counter clock ?

Comment: Usually that's the part of the problem – which direction to take to integrate over. But if it's not given, then yes, technically you need to consider both options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $e^z$ is entire, that is, holomorphic in all of $\Bbb C$, and

$\dfrac{d(e^z)}{dz} = e^z, \tag{1}$

we have

$\int_\gamma \dfrac{d(e^z)}{dz}dz = \int_\gamma e^z dz \tag{2}$

for any path $\gamma:[a, b] \to \Bbb C$, where $[a, b] \subset \Bbb R$ is a closed interval.  Furthermore,

$\int_\gamma \dfrac{d(e^z)}{dz}dz = e^{\gamma(b)} - e^{\gamma(a)}, \tag{3}$

so if $\gamma$ joins $1$ and $i$, that is, $\gamma(a) = 1$ and $\gamma(b) = i$, then we find from (2) that

$\int_\gamma e^z dz = e^i - e^1, \tag{4}$

right?  And we can take it a little further by noting that

$e^i = \cos 1 + i\sin 1, \tag{5}$

whence

$\int_\gamma e^z dz = e^i - e^1 = (\cos 1 - 1) + i\sin 1; \tag{6}$

since $e^z$ is holomorphic on the *entirety* of $\Bbb C$, the exact path $\gamma$ doesn't matter; it's the endpoints which influence the integral.

You can read all about this stuff [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative_%28complex_analysis%29).

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 0):

The integral around the whole circle is $0$ by Cauchy's theorem.  The integral around your particular arc is not.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $e^z$ is analytic everywhere, so you can compute the integral exactly as you would for a real integral.